# djangogirls tutorial pythonanywhere application stopped working

Tags: pythonanywhere

I successfully deployed to pythonanywhere free account per the tutorial. It worked through a number of lessons. Then I started getting host not allowed errors. I have messed around and gotten nowhere and now git is not longer connected and pulls do not work and bash does not automatically activate my virtual environment. Is there a way I can scrap everything and start over setting up the free account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to start again is to contact PythonAnywhere support and request an account deletion. Then you can register again for a new account.